# Having two ContentTypeRecords to know about each other

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, orchardcms

Consider the case where i need a ProductPartRecord type and a ManufacturerPartRecord type. 
In the fist type i need to know who's the manufacturer of this part, hence it would be convenient to use a property of type ManufacturerPartRecord.
In the second type i would like to know the products this manufacturer makes, hence it would be convenient to have a property of type IList.

Apparently it is a 1 to many relationship.
Is this a bad practice to put Records in Records and is this even possible, because i'm facing troubles implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. And here's how to do it:

1. In the migrations, add a column to the `ProductPartRecord` which is of type `int` and the name should be `ManufacturerPartRecord_Id` assuming that `Id` is the name of primary key inside the `ManufacturerPartRecord` table.
2. Create a foreign key inside the migrations. It should look something like this `SchemaBuilder.CreateForeignKey("Product_Manufacturer", "ProductPartRecord", new[] { "ManufacturerPartRecord_Id" }, "ManufacturerPartRecord", new[] { "Id" });`
3. Inside the `ManufacturerPartRecord` model class, you should add a new property which you'll use for list of products - `public virtual IList<ProductPartRecord> ProductPartRecords { get; set; }`
4. Inside the `ProductPartRecord` model class, you should add a new property which you'll use to get manufacturer - `public virtual ManufacturerPartRecord ManufacturerPartRecord { get; set; }`

It should be all set now to automatically get manufacturer for you products and vice versa.

If you don't want this to happen automatically, you should create a service class which will get `IRepository<ManufacturerPartRecord>` or `IRepository<ProductPartRecord>` via constructor injection and handle getting and saving lists yourself.

Comment: That was very explanatory. I have an additional question. 
Is the last paragraph a substitution for step '2' or the foreign key must be created either way. I'm asking this because in the pluralsight's Advanced Orchard course i saw, the relation was created w/o a fk, rather a table that contained both records' Ids (for ref, see UpdateFrom5() in the [Pluralsight.Movies](https://bitbucket.org/kevinkuebler/pluralsight.movies/src/0b66885d05936a56bfc46cd56cf23741e43b9209/Migrations.cs?at=default) repo)

Comment: It's optional. If you create a foreign key, it will be created inside the database and the database itself will enforce it, meaning that it will throw error if you try to add ManufacturerId that doesn't exist yet to some Product or if you try deleting Manufacturer whose ID some of the Products are still using.

Comment: So now, when editing the Product, I show a list of manufacturer names in the view. I select one of those manufacturers, and then the request goes to the Product driver as usual, where, i can't assign the name(string) that i selected to the ProductPart's Manufacturer (ManufacturerPartRecord) property. I would like to use the manufacturer repository to find the record by the name that i selected. What i can't find out is however how to access that name from the ProductDriver.Editor() method.

Comment: It depends whether you connected the parts automatically or are you handling it yourself. Whichever path you took, when showing a list of manufacturer names, you should set their IDs as values of list items and you should set the name of the select list to be for example @Html.FieldNameFor(m => m.ManufacturerPartRecord.Id) if you're using automatic part connection or for example @Html.FieldNameFor(m => m.ManufacturerPartRecordId) if you're using manual connection.

After that, once you call updater.TryUpdateModel() your id property should be set..

Comment: After that, you can create a constructor of your driver that takes a parameter of type `IRepository<ManufacturerPartRecord>` and save the value to some field (for example: `private readonly IRepository<ManufacturerPartRecord> _repository;`).

After you've created that field, you can use the repository right after the `updater.TryUpdateModel()` like this: `part.ManufacturerPartRecord = _repository.Get(part.ManufacturerPartRecordId);`

Comment: What u described in the last comment is what i want to do, either by manufacturer name or by id (preferable). As to the initial response - It seems that's where my flaw is, i'll check what am i doing wrong when rendering the Edit view and why afterwards the updater wont set the Manufacturer.
P.S. I haven't used NHibernate much, so atm I'm trying to draw the line of what NHibernate does and what Orchard does in perspective of persistance/mapping/querying records.

Comment: NHibernate handles communication with the database (the IRepository is a wrapper around NHibernate). Autofac calls constructor with the correct parameters and does initial ContentPart creation using NHibernate. Updater is classic MVC updater and it updates model via name matching or in other words it matches the names of the fields from Views with the property names of model. You can also get to the values of those fields manually via `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` property (it's of type `NameValueCollection`)..